Reversing a First Difference Error Correction Model: Converting the Forecasted FD results back
I'm doing a study on how market rates affect interest rates. The model I've chosen is an Error Correction Model. I address the unit root issue in my dataset by taking the first difference. I then ran the ECM model. Based on my model results, I forecasted future rates. What I want to do now is convert the forecasted, differenced, results, to forecasted rates.  Below is an example of my data and forecasted differenced results and functional form:
ecm <- lm(D(Rt) ~ dplyr::lag(D(Rt)) + dplyr::lag(D(Rt), 2) + 
           D(MRt)) + dplyr::lag(D(MRt))+dplyr::lag(D(MRt), 2) + 
           dplyr::lag(res), merge(X, res))

Where Rt is the rate, MRt is the market rate and res is the EC variable

My question: I need to convert the forecasted-differenced results back to its original form. In order to do this, I believe I need to take the cumulative sum, of the forecasted-differenced results but where does this conversion begin? Is the formula:

And then...

So, the original form for t=4 is equal to 0.01699 and for t=5 the original form is 0.01828
